# count the number of pages in a docx-document

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I got a word file and I want to count how many pages are in it.

The file has been created with Docx4Java.

Anyone did this before?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268541/how-to-get-page-sheet-count-of-word-excel-documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docx4j doesn't have a page layout model, so it can't tell you a page count.

You can get an approximate page count by using FOP's page layout model.  docx4j's PDF output now supports a "2 pass" generation:

- first pass calculates the page count(s)
- second pass generates the pdf

See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/fo/AbstractPlaceholderLookup.java
and
https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/fo/ApacheFORenderer.java

So doing the first pass would give you (approximately) what you want.  This uses org.apache.fop.apps.FormattingResults which records the number of pages in a page sequence, or in the document as a whole.

An alternative approach might be to use LibreOffice/OpenOffice (or Microsoft Word, for that matter).