# Remove blank page in docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to conditionally remove/add page break in my generated document with docx4j. If page content fits within the whole page then my added page break creates a blank page. I am using following code to remove page break:

```java
List<Object> paragraphs = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(),P.class);
for(Object objP:paragraphs) {
    P para = (P) objP;
    /***/
    List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(para,Text.class);

    List<Object> brs = getAllElementFromObject(para,Br.class);

    if(brs.size()==1 && checkPageBreak((Br)brs.get(0)) && texts.size()== 0)
        remove(template.getMainDocumentPart().getContent(), para);
```

}

But this removes useful page break as well. So is there any way where I can check the page content height dynamically?  Or any other solution?

Comment: Good question: the trick to all this is having a 'page layout model', i.e. a concept of what constitutes a page of content so that you know which page breaks should be removed. This answer may assist with that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18476213/125750

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and was able to avoid blank pages by using a section break instead of a Page break

Click below option to see all the page/section breaks
[image: show/hide]

Replace Page break after which the blank page appears with a Section break

[image: steps to insert section break]