# Count pages/lines in a word file that was edited with docx4j

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I found some posts here how to count pages/lines with the apache-poi library.
But my code already uses docx4j right now, it would be too much work to completely replace that.

Therefore my question is, how can I get from an object of type `WordprocessingMLPackage` to an object of type `XWPFDocument` in order to count the lines and pages of my current document.

```
private XWPFDocument convertDocx4J(WordprocessingMLPackage wp) {
    XWPFDocument oiDoc = null;

    //TODO...

    return oiDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to go from docx4j's WordprocessingMLPackage to POI would be to use docx4j's API to save as docx, then POI's to load.

But you can get page info from docx4j; see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc/TocGenerator.java#L657

Comment: If I save it, how can I delete it later?
How to use that TocGenerator to get the number of pages from my WordprocessingMLPackage object?
Can you come up or do you know where to find any example code for either of those questions?

Comment: Put a bookmark at the end of the document, then parse the JSON response to find the page number associated with that: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc/TocGenerator.java#L746